# Changed 'txt.cfg' file in a lubuntu live usb and now its 'read only'

Tags: lubuntu, live-usb

Well, I was looking for edit the `txt.cfg` file in `/cdrom/syslinux/` directory to add my locale configuration and it chooses my keyboard settings automatic. And to bypass the `Try Ubuntu` screen.

But I forget, I use the usb stick with persistence. When changing the file content I forget to mention this in the append line... No backuped the old content. Now the usb boot shows the `Try ubuntu without changes` screen, with just one option, and choose language like I've write, but no persistence.

When tryed to change the file content again, I was unable. The system now gaves me an error message, saying the file is read only, even with sudo powers. How to change this again and come back with my persistence?

Comment: "saying the file is read only, even with sudo powers." this probably means you mounted it read-only. If so: remount with write :)

Comment: How to do that if I`ve removed the options in the splash screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, done.

When the `Try Lubuntu without changes` screen start, choose language and then, before select any option, press `F6`. A little window with 'boot options' will pop-up. Esc, an then the append line of txt.cfg will be there, and you can edit it. Simple write `persistent` there. Something like this:

`file=/cdrom/preseed/lubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash noprompt locale=pt --`

After that, the system boots with my old persistence, wirelles passwords and everything saved and just like before.
So you'll be able to modify the `txt.cfg` file again. Simple write `persistence` again and it will be fine.